# Decide whether the following series converge or diverge; in the case of convergence, indicate whether it is absolute:

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, divergent-series

**Decide whether the following series converge or diverge; in the case of convergence, indicate whether it is absolute: (i) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-1/2}i^n$ ; (ii) $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n^{-1}[Log(n+iy)]^{-2}$ ; (iii) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n!)^2[(2n)!]^{-1}(3+4i)^n$ ; (iv) $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}2^n\sec(ni)$ ; (v) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+n^{-1})^{-n^2}(1+2i)^ne^{ni}$.**

(i) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|n^{-1/2}i^n|=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0$ so, I can not decide if the series converges or diverges by this method, note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |n^{-1/2}i^n|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-1/2}$ is a series p where $p=1/2$ and so I could say that the series diverges?

(ii) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|n^{-1}[Log(n+iy)]^{-2}|=0$ so, I can not decide if the series converges or diverges by this method

How can I determine if these series diverge or converge in an efficient and easy way? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(i)** With Raabe's test it's converge
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(1-\Big|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big|\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)<\dfrac12$$

**(v)** With Root's test it's converge
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\Big|\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^{-n^2}(1+2i)^ne^{ni}\Big|}=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{e}<1$$

Comment: $$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)}=1.
$$

Comment: At the end $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$

Comment: Sorry, it should be $$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
But your argument will conclude that the series $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ (of course this is divergent) converges.

Comment: @ts375_zk26 You right. I must told it is conditionally converges. Since $\dfrac12<1$ the convergence is not absolutely, but I intuitively know that it's converges conditionally and don't have reason!

Comment: The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-1/2}i^n$ does not converge absolutely, but converges conditionally. Note that
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (2m)^{-1/2}i^{(2m)}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{2m}}
$$
converges conditionally. Also $$
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (2m+1)^{-1/2}i^{(2m+1)}=i\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{2m+1}}
$$
converges conditionally. So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-1/2}i^n$ converges conditionally.

Comment: I knew that but I thought we can't separate terms in series with positive and negative terms!

Comment: This is the last comment.$$
\sum_{n=1}^{2N} n^{-1/2}i^n=\sum_{m=1}^N\left(\frac{i^{2m-1}}{\sqrt{2m-1}}  +\frac{i^{2m}}{\sqrt{2m}}\right)=i\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{2m+1}}+\sum_{m=1}^N\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{2m}}
$$
and $$
\sum_{n=1}^{2N+1} n^{-1/2}i^n=i\sum_{m=0}^{N}\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{2m+1}}+\sum_{m=1}^N\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{2m}}.
$$
I think nothing is wrong.

Comment: @MyGlasses 
For (iii) I could use the criterion of the integral? Taking $f(x)=\frac{1}{xLog^2(x+iy)}$ and so $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{xLog^2(x+iy)}=\frac{1}{2}$, with which $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n^{-1}[Log(n+iy)]^{-2}$ would be convergent?

Comment: @ts375_zk26 For (iii) I could use the quotient criterion? then $\lim sup_{n\to \infty}|\frac{((n+1)!)(3+4i)^{n+1}(2n)!}{(2(n+1))!(n!)^2(3+4i)^n}|=\frac{5}{4}>1$ and so the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n!)^2[(2n)!]^{-1}(3+4i)^n$ would be divergent?

Comment: @Nash I've no idea about functional series (ii), it's so hard and I know integral test for real case, is that works for complex case? What condition it must have?

Comment: @Nash  For (iii) the quotient criterion is useful. The series is divergent as you mentioned.

Comment: @MyGlasses I do not know if that works for the complex case, I hope someone will tell us yes, because it would be very helpful to know that!

Comment: @ts375_zk26 For (iv) I could say that $\lim_{n\to \infty}2^n\sec(ni)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2^n}{cos(ni)}=\infty \neq 0$ and so the series would be divergent?

Comment: @Nash $$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty 2^n\sec(ni)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty 2^n\frac{2}{e^{i(ni)}+e^{-i(ni)}}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{2^{n+1}}{e^{-n}+e^n}.
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{n+1}}{e^{-n}+e^n}<\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{n+1}}{e^n}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n<+\infty,$$
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{2^{n+1}}{e^{-n}+e^n}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{2^{-m+1}}{e^{m}+e^{-m}}<\sum_{m=1}^\infty2^{-m+1}<+\infty.
$$
So $
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty 2^n\sec(ni)
$ converges.